# Convert UTF-8 octets to unicode code points

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a set of UTF-8 octets  and I need to convert them back to unicode code points. How can I do this in python.

e.g. UTF-8 octet ['0xc5','0x81'] should be converted to 0x141 codepoint.

Comment: Are you 100% that's what you've got? Could I please ask a very silly question: How on earth did you manage to acquire the data in that format?

Comment: Are you trying to convert to code points or to "Python" Unicode string? That is quite big difference because Python Unicode string holds UTF-16 and one code point may be encoded with two "characters" -- surrogate pair. Be aware of what you want. The accepted answer would not give you code points but UTF-16 encoded string.

Comment: I got the values from a conversion function which converts from our internal encoding to utf-8 and vice versa.

Comment: @Artyom: I want to convert utf-8 to unicode code points. SO how to get unicode code points instead of python unicode string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Python 3.x:

In Python 3.x, `str` is the class for Unicode text, and `bytes` is for containing octets.

If by "octets" you really mean strings in the form '0xc5' (rather than '\xc5') you can convert to `bytes` like this:

```
>>> bytes(int(x,0) for x in ['0xc5', '0x81'])
b'\xc5\x81'
```

You can then convert to `str` (ie: Unicode) using the `str` constructor...

```
>>> str(b'\xc5\x81', 'utf-8')
'Ł'
```

...or by calling `.decode('utf-8')` on the `bytes` object:

```
>>> b'\xc5\x81'.decode('utf-8')
'Ł'
>>> hex(ord('Ł'))
'0x141'
```

#### Pre-3.x:

Prior to 3.x, the `str` type was a byte array, and `unicode` was for Unicode text.

Again, if by "octets" you really mean strings in the form '0xc5' (rather than '\xc5') you can convert them like this:

```
>>> ''.join(chr(int(x,0)) for x in ['0xc5', '0x81'])
'\xc5\x81'
```

You can then convert to `unicode` using the constructor...

```
>>> unicode('\xc5\x81', 'utf-8')
u'\u0141'
```

...or by calling `.decode('utf-8')` on the `str`:

```
>>> '\xc5\x81'.decode('utf-8')
u'\u0141'
```

Comment: +1: Also, int(x,0) has the advantage of permitting mixed base octect string, for example, ['0xc5', '0x81', '0305', '0201'] are the hex and octal representations of the same. int(x,16) would misinterpret the octal strings in this input

Comment: @mhawke: to detect errors, `int(x, 16)` could be used: `bytearray(int(x, 16) for x in ['0xc5', '0x81']).decode('utf-8', 'surrogatepass')` (single-source Python 2/3 code)

Comment: @thang The answer was originally written for pre-3.x. There is no `unicode` in 3.x anymore -- it is now `str`. I've updated the answer to have both 2.x and 3.x versions.

Answer (score 6):

In lovely 3.x, where all `str`s are Unicode, and `bytes` are what `str`s used to be:

```
>>> s = str(bytes([0xc5, 0x81]), 'utf-8')
>>> s
'Ł'
>>> ord(s)
321
>>> hex(ord(s))
'0x141'
```

Which is what you asked for.

Comment: you could use `bytearray([0xc5, 0x81]).decode('utf-8')` that works on both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

```
l = ['0xc5','0x81']
s = ''.join([chr(int(c, 16)) for c in l]).decode('utf8')
s
>>> u'\u0141'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> "".join((chr(int(x,16)) for x in ['0xc5','0x81'])).decode("utf8")
u'\u0141'
```