# Python: Replace character by its Unicode-representation

Tags: python, string, replace, utf-8

How can I replace all characters in a string by their Unicode-representation?

Minimal example:

```
>>> s = 'ä'
>>> new = some_function(s, 'unicode')
>>> new
'\u00E4'
```

Comment: That's not a UTF-8 representation, it's a Unicode representation. You need to learn the difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert UTF-8 octets to unicode code points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864701/convert-utf-8-octets-to-unicode-code-points)

Comment: @Mark: Sorry, I mixed it up.

Comment: Another question, is this Python 2 or Python 3? There's a difference in the way they treat string literals. In Python 2 you'll get a byte string that is the same encoding as your program, but in Python 3 you'll get a Unicode string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to convert from a byte string to a Unicode string:

```
u = s.decode('utf-8')
```

The second step is to create a new string with every character replaced by its Unicode escape sequence.

```
new = ''.join('\\u{:04x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in u)
```

If your intent was only to replace the non-ASCII characters then a slight modification will do:

```
new = ''.join(c if 32 <= ord(c) < 128 else '\\u{:04x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in u)
```

Note that the `\u0000` notation only works for Unicode codepoints in the base Unicode plane. You need the `\U00000000` notation for anything larger. You can also use `\x00` notation for anything less than 256. The following handles all cases and is probably a bit easier to read:

```
def unicode_notation(c):
    x = ord(c)
    if 32 <= x < 128:
        return c
    if x < 256:
        return '\\x{:02x}'.format(x)
    if x < 0x10000:
        return '\\u{:04x}'.format(x)
    return '\\U{:08x}'.format(x)

new = ''.join(unicode_notation(c) for c in u)
```

Comment: Modifying Valentin's solution (→ new = ''.join([i if 32 <= ord(i) < 128 else '\\u' + repr(i)[4:-1].upper().rjust(4, '0') for i in string])) leaded me to nearly the same as your third line. Thanks for the detailed explanation with "unicode_notation". :)

Comment: @CFP I thought `format` was a little cleaner than all the text manipulation, but it's all a matter of style so whatever works for you. Remember my warning about characters greater than 0x10000 though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by “unicode representation”.
Here is solution to my interpretation of your question.

For Python 3:

```
print('\\u' + hex(ord('ä'))[2:].upper().rjust(4, '0'))
```

For Python 2:

```
print('\\u' + repr(u'ä')[4:-1].upper().rjust(4, '0'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for all non-ascii chars. Combining yours and Mark's was successfull.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that's what you want?

```
>>> new = s.decode('utf-8')
```