# Python 3.6, utf-8 to unicode conversion, string with double backslashes

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

There are many questions about utf-8 > unicode conversion, but I still haven't found answer for my issue.

Lets have strings like this:

```
a = "Je-li pro za\\xc5\\x99azov\\xc3\\xa1n\\xc3\\xad"
```

Python 3.6 understands this string like *Je-li pro za\xc5\x99azov\xc3\xa1n\xc3\xad*. I need to convert this utf-8-like string to unicode representation. The final result should be *Je-li pro zařazování*.

With `a.decode("utf-8")` I get *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'*, because Python means the object is already decoded.

If I convert it to bytes first with `bytes(a, "utf-8")`, the backslashes are doubled only and `.decode("utf-8")` returns it to my current `a` again.

How to get unicode string *Je-li pro zařazování* from this `a`?

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864701/convert-utf-8-octets-to-unicode-code-points) help? (and before you say "no it's not" it doesn't use `bytes(a,"utf-8")`, you need better explanation.)

Comment: And... why do you have two ``\``s?

Comment: [how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181)

Comment: Why two backslashes... It is result of one strange API, that returns some characters decoded and some not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert "\x" escaped string into readable string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218987/convert-x-escaped-string-into-readable-string-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to encode/decode 4 times to get the desired result:

```python
print(
  "Je-li pro za\\xc5\\x99azov\\xc3\\xa1n\\xc3\\xad"

  # actually any encoding support printable ASCII would work, for example utf-8
  .encode('ascii')

  # unescape the string
  # source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885197
  .decode('unicode-escape')

  # latin-1 also works, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7048745
  .encode('iso-8859-1')

  # finally
  .decode('utf-8')
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZA9b8IwEIZ3fsUJBkAipBFESdiqTnTtynJ1LsTC@Fx/AOHPp04QVbt0eXUfuud9bdP5lvWm742V2i8mANN3SpQEYxnueDjcRB6lqvDOl6HbRMFM/5T1dBKPZoDCB1SqA9QdkBZcS30EF4xh62Gk46cieP142@/hykHVUe1pBQ1boBueTdwG3yRl5K1HAi3m6ISU8@XDI2hyAg2Bbwmcj8zjOHccrKAdtN4bt0tT51Gc@EK2UXxdCz6nmGZlmWdVMbBrerCDlkORPKBPE4Ve6iQDVI7HhG4Fjugf@FdavGzLYpv/Di4dJ9GySrInuJF6@KA/CYbnxv2y778B)

Besides, consider telling your target program (data source) to give different output format (byte array or base64 encoded, for example), if you can.

The unsafe-but-shorter way:

```python
st = "Je-li pro za\\xc5\\x99azov\\xc3\\xa1n\\xc3\\xad"
print(eval("b'"+st+"'").decode('utf-8'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v7hEwVZByStVNydToaAoX6EqMSamItkUSFhaJlbll4F4xkAi0TAPzkxR4iooyswr0UgtS8zRUEpSV9IuLtFWUlfS1EtJTc5PSdVQLy1J07VQ19T8/x8A)

There are `ast.literal_eval`, but it may not worth using here.