# Python3 using UTF-8 data from bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, data-conversion

I am using Python 3.7.

I have data being read from two files. Both contain UTF-8 data (well, technically...). One is properly "encoded" into UTF-8 while the other was written as a decoded bytestream.

```
# 'ba' is the on-disk form of the first (correctly-encoded) file
>>> ba = b'\xc3\xb6'
>>> ba
b'\xc3\xb6'
>>> ba.decode()
'ö'

# 'bb' is the on-disk form of the incorrectly-encoded second file
>>> bb = b'\xf6'
>>> bb
b'\xf6'

# 'bs' is the unicode version of the same byte value as bb
>>> bs = '\xf6'
>>> bs
'ö'

# If I try to decode ba, I get the correct value.
>>> ba.decode()
'ö'
>>> ba.decode() == bs
True

# But if I try to decode bb, I get an encoding error.
>>> bb.decode() == bs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How do I turn `bb` from an incorrectly-encoded `bytes` object into a correctly-decoded `str` object? I am okay with making an assumption that `bb` is UTF-8 decoded data blob instead of garbage.

I have already done a little bit of searching to try to solve it myself. It's honestly rather difficult to filter the Python2.x cruft from Google results though.

I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49756591/1111557) helpful since it mentions the ["unicode-escape" encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) which appears to do what I want it to do:

```
>>> bb.decode('unicode-escape')
'ö'
>>> bb.decode('unicode-escape') == bs
True
```

However, it is not clear to me what side effects that 'unicode-escape' might present outside of this specific scenario. It seems to indicate that it reads escaped encodings, but I don't believe `b'\xf6'` is escaped: I believe it is a single byte represented as hex to the python interpreter. I would assume that an escaped encoding would be something like `b'\\xf6'`, which should be four bytes: ASCII backslash, ASCII 'x', ASCII 'f', and ASCII '6'.

```
>>> bc
b'\\xf6'
>>> bc.decode()
'\\xf6'
>>> bc == bb
False
>>> bc.decode('unicode-escape')
'ö'
```

To be clear, I do *not* want such escaping to be processed! I would want the UTF version of `bc` to be equal to `'\\xf6'` whose `len` is 4.

Edit1:
A user seems to think this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552555/1111557). I have read the other question and do not see how this is a duplicate. The other question talks about latin-1. I do not believe I am dealing with latin-1 data.

Comment: Your files do not both contain UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your help @user2357112